# Can't get result from task list

Tags: c#, async-await

I have this `async` function that returns a `Task`

```
public async Task<SettingModel> GetSetting(string key)
{
    var rootPath = _hostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath;
    using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(rootPath + key + "settings.json"))
    {
        string json = await r.ReadToEndAsync();
        var settings = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SettingModel>(json);
        return settings;
    }
}
```

Now I want to get all settings and then wait until all is completed like this

```
public async Task GetData(List<string> keys)
{
    var taskList = new List<Task>();
    foreach(var key in keys)
    {
        taskList.Add(GetSetting(key));
    }

    await Task.WhenAll(taskList.ToList());

    foreach (var task in taskList)
    {
        task.Result // here its not working. The task don't have a result :(
    }
}
```

How to get the data from the task?

Comment: I'm thinking that `taskList` should have the type `List<Task<SettingModel>>`.

Comment: Where´s the task.run happening?

Comment: @C.Gonzalez Nowhere.  There's no reason to call `Task.Run` here.

Comment: You´re right, my mistake!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Change your `taskList` to `List<Task<SettingModel>>` and also don't use `task.Result` to avoid [Deadlock](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html). Your code should be something like this:

```
var taskList = new List<Task<SettingModel>>();

foreach(var key in keys)
{
    taskList.Add(GetSetting(key));
}

var result = await Task.WhenAll(taskList.ToList()).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Comment: Since all tasks are awaited in `await Task.WhenAll` in OP's case, `.Result` wouldn't cause deadlock. (Of course better to avoid it if you are not sure about what you are doing)

Comment: Great answer! Thanks for your help.